# netCDF4-Python Plotting variables

Tags: python, plot, netcdf

[image]I would like to plot a selection of variables from a netCDF file using netCDF4-Python.I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pylab import *
from netCDF4 import Dataset
pals = Dataset('pals_amplero_2003_2006_ecmwf_v1.nc4', "a",format='NETCDF4')
print (pals.variables.keys())
print (pals.variables['Rainf'])
print (pals.variables['Evap'])
print (pals.variables['time'])
evap = pals.variables['Evap'][:,:]
rain = pals.variables['Rainf'][:,:]
subplot(2,1,1)
pcolor(evap)
subplot(2,1,2)
pcolor(rain)
```

Unfortunately, it outputs an error message (more detailed in the enclosed document):

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

For info the following is the output of the print commands

```
odict_keys(['DelIntercept', 'DelSWE', 'DelSoilMoist', 'Evap', 'Qs', 'Qsb',      'Qsm', 'Rainf', 'Snowf', 'lat', 'lon', 'nlevs', 'time', 'timestp', 'M_fieldcap', 'M_sat', 'M_wilt', 'SoilDepth', 'CanopInt', 'Conds', 'ECanop', 'ESoil', 'RootMoist', 'SubSnow', 'TVeg', 'DelColdCont', 'DelSoilHeat', 'LWnet', 'LWup', 'Qf', 'Qg', 'Qh', 'Qle', 'SWnet', 'Fdepth', 'HFLUXRF', 'IceFrac', 'MFLUXRF', 'SAlbedo', 'SnowDepth', 'SnowFrac', 'Tdepth', 'WSN', 'AvgSurfT', 'HLICE', 'HLML', 'SWE', 'SnowT', 'SoilMoist', 'SoilTemp', 'TLBOT', 'TLICE', 'TLMNW', 'TLSF', 'TLWML', 'icetemp', 'snowdens', 'Albedo', 'BaresoilT', 'RH2m', 'RadT', 'T2m', 'VegT', 'Bgain', 'Biomstr', 'Biomstr2', 'Bloss', 'biomass', 'lai', 'Ag', 'An', 'CO2flux', 'Rd', 'Reco', 'Rsoil_str'])
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 Rainf(time, y, x)
units: mm/day
long_name: Rainfall rate
associate: time y x
missing_value: 1e+20
time_representation: average over past model timestep
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (70084, 1, 1)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 Evap(time, y, x)
units: mm/day
long_name: Total evapotranspiration
associate: time y x
missing_value: 1e+20
time_representation: average over past model timestep
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (70084, 1, 1)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
units: seconds since 2003-01-01 00:00:00
long_name: Time in seconds
Time_label: Start of output interval
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (70084,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used
```

Comment: You don't show where/how your read `prec`. Normally your code should work; e.g. `evap` has a three dimensional shape in the NetCDF file, but you slice (`[:,:]`) the first two dimensions out of it, so this should work with `pcolor`. Could be that `prec` has more than two dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, you pointed out an error in my code there is no variable "prec". There is only "evap" and "rain" and both of them have 3 dimensions that I slice using [:,:] I just don't understand the error!

Comment: Me neither. Can you add the full error message (at least including which line causes the error)?

Comment: Ok! I re-edit my question now with the full error message. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally see the problem. Take this example (a random NetCDF file):

```
ncdump -h th.xz.nc
```

Gives (amongst other things):

```
float th(time, z, x, y) ;
```

So the variable `th` has 4 dimensions. If you read/plot this in a similar way as in your code:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

nc = nc4.Dataset('th.xz.nc')
th = nc.variables['th'][:,:]

pl.figure()
pl.pcolor(th)
```

It gives the same error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Why? The slicing with `[:,:]` (or `[:]`, or `[:,:,:]`) will still give you more than two dimensions:

```
print(th.shape)
```

> (9, 32, 32, 1)

while `pcolor` expects a two-dimensional array. The solution is simple; you need to select which 2D slice you want to show, for example `pcolor(evap[0,:,:])` (`x-y` slice) or `pcolor(evap[:,0,:])` (`time-x` slice), or ...